# How can I enumerate and add margin_titles to each subplot in a seaborn lmplot facetgrid?

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I have the following attached lmplot facetgrid [image: lmplot facetgrid]

To start with, I want to simplify the title of each subplot, to only have corpus = {corpus name}.

I am generating these plots using the lmplot as per

```
g=sns.lmplot('x', 'y', data=test_plot, col='corpus', hue = 'monotonicity', row='measure', sharey=True, sharex=True, height=2.5,aspect=1.25, truncate=False, scatter_kws={"marker": "D", "s": 20})

g=(g.set_axis_labels("Max-Min (measure)", "Max-Min (comp measure)")
        .set(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(-.1, 1))
        .fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=.02))
```

I want to use the facetgrid `margin_title` option to put the measure value on the right y-axis, but get `lmplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'margin_titles'`

I then tried using a facetgrid, as per:

```
p = sns.FacetGrid(data = test_plot,
                           col = 'corpus',
                           hue = 'monotonicity',
                           row = 'measure',
                           margin_titles=True)
    

p.map(sns.lmplot, 'diff_', 'score_diff',  data=test_plot, he='monotonicity', truncate=False, scatter_kws={"marker": "D", "s": 20})
```

but then I get an error about `lmplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'` (cannot figure out why that is being thrown?).

My second problem is that I want to add a letter/enumeration to each subplot's title, as in `(a), ..., (i)`, but for the life of me cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example so we have data to help you? See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your custom needs, consider iterating through all the axes of the FacetGrid after running your `lmplot`. Regarding your specific error, [`seaborn.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) is a FacetGrid so will conflict if nested in another FacetGrid as tried in your second attempt. Also, in below solution, do not re-assign `g` to axes setup which returns `NoneType`:

```py
#... SAME lmplot ...

(
  g.set_axis_labels("Max-Min (measure)", "Max-Min (comp measure)")
   .set(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(-.1, 1))
   .fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=.02)
)

alpha = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
axes = g.axes.flatten()

# ADJUST ALL AXES TITLES
for ax, letter in zip(axes, alpha[:len(axes)]):
    ttl = ax.get_title().split("|")[1].strip()   # GET CURRENT TITLE
    ax.set_title(f"({letter}) {ttl}")            # SET NEW TITLE

# ADJUST SELECT AXES Y LABELS
for i, m in zip(range(0, len(axes), 3), test_plot["measure"].unique()):
    axes[i].set_ylabel(m)
```

**Input** *(purely random data for demonstration)*

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(1172021)

test_plot = pd.DataFrame({
    'measure': np.random.choice(["precision", "recall", "F1-score"], 500),
    'corpus': np.random.choice(["Fairview", "i2b2", "MiPACQ"], 500),
    'monotonicity': np.random.choice(["increasing", "non", "decreasing"], 500),
    'x': np.random.uniform(0, 1, 500),
    'y': np.random.uniform(0, 1, 500)
})
```

**Output**

[image: FacetGrid Plot Output]

Comment: Thanks! This works great, only issue is that the y-axis label needs to remain on the left (`Max-Min (comp measure)` in my case), and the three labels for the performance measures (precision, recall and F1-score) should be on the right y-axis (which is why I wanted to use `margin_titles=True`).

Comment: Got it. I just modified the second for loop, to use `y_title = 'Max - Min (' + m +')'`

Comment: Great to hear! Glad you got it to work. I was not quite sure your desired result.